# React HOC component call async action, triggered twice using componentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this piece of code

```
export default function CheckHasSentGift(TransformedComponent) {
  @connect(state=>state.global,{fetchGift})
   class WithRedirect extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      this.props.fetchGift('sent')
    }

    render() {
      this.props.sentGiftId && 
      !this.props.location.pathname.includes('sent') && 
      return <Redirect to={`/app/gift/${this.props.sentGiftId}/sent`} />

      return <TransformedComponent { ...this.props } />
    }
  }

  return WithRedirect
}
```

and this is my route

```
<Route exact path='/app' component={CheckHasSentGift(App)} />
```

I don't have problem making the redirect, it worked, but I saw 2 calls to fetchGift api in my network tab. I then debug by doing this in the render method

```
render() {
  //this.props.sentGiftId && 
  //!this.props.location.pathname.includes('sent') && 
  //return <Redirect to={`/app/gift/${this.props.sentGiftId}/sent`} />

  console.log('check render')

  return <h1>test</h1>
  //return <TransformedComponent { ...this.props } />
}
```

And the render only render once, how come the componentWillMount can fire twice after the redirected?

Comment: I think this issue is specifically addressed here by the react team: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount. And also here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html. I think the ideal thing to do is to make async calls in constructor method

Answer (score 0):

Actually `componentWillMount` is deprecated starting with React.v16.3 and it's better to use [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) to start fetching data.

> And the render only render once, how come the componentWillMount can
>   fire twice after the redirected?

Place your console.log to `componentWillMount` to see if it's called twice.

Also make sure that first request is not a [preflight request (OPTIONS method)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) which browser will fire to describe communication between server. You can check it in Network Tab in a browser developer tools.

Comment: Tried componentDidMount, triggered twice, I then put in constructor, worked fine. componentDidMount fire after the first render called, why use it for async call?

Comment: @JamieAden it's hard to tell why this component is created twice, without having a full example. The documentation says it's the best place to start an async call. componentWillMount could lead to some memory leaks (e.g. it is called while server sider rendering).